# How to underline text in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension for Grammar Check, similar to Grammarly.

One of the topics I struggle with is the highlight of the word that should be corrected.
How can I highlight a text in a DIV (contenteditable) using Chrome Extension, so that it will not be part of the DIV, or the textarea?

I'm looking for something similar to this:

[image: Errors underlying in Grammarly]

Thanks!

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114185/chrome-extension-create-div-on-text-highlight

Comment: No... The other question deals with displaying a DIV when a text is highlighted. I'm looking for a way to underline a text without it being highlighted.